# What's wrong with this Genesis PHP WordPress plugin code?

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Add Fontawesome Animation
* Plugin URI: ...
* Description: This plugin is used to animate Fontawesome icons
* Version: 1.0.0
* Author: ...
* Author URI: ...
* License: GPLv2
* * */

// Enqueue font-awesome-animation.css
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'add_fontawesome_animation' );
function add_fontawesome_animation() {
    wp_enqueue_style('font_awesome_animation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome-animation.css' );
}
```

Objective: load font-awesome-animation.css so FontAwesome icons can animate.

Using: PhpStorm and just getting started with Genesis. I am using the genesis-sample child theme and for the most part all is going reasonably well publishing posts and learning to use code to mod the templates.

The FontAwesome icons will animate when I @import url("css/font-awesome-animation.css") into the style.css file else I have not been able to enqueue font-awesome-animation.css from functions.php or the plugin as shown above. I get no observable errors in the editor or in the page nor do I get the typical all white page when there are errors in the PHP. Something is FUBAR and I don't know how to do this type of debugging in WordPress yet so I need to know what may be wrong with the code and suggestions about how to debug this type of SNAFU. Is there some type of Response.Write I can use to show me pathing and such?

Comment: it looks like you're adding a `wp_enqueue_style` call into the `wp_enqueue_style` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the hook you are using to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. From the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts):

> wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that
>   are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is used for
>   enqueuing **both** scripts and styles.

Also `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will not work for you if you are making a plugin. That is only for use in themes/child themes. If you are calling this from your main plugin file you  can use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` instead. Again, from [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url):

> Gets the URL (with trailing slash) for the plugin **FILE** passed in

In this case we are passing the [PHP magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__` to get the uri for the main plugin file **with a trailing slash**.

So your code would look like the following:

```
<?php
// Enqueue font-awesome-animation.css
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_fontawesome_animation' );

function add_fontawesome_animation() {
wp_enqueue_style('font_awesome_animation', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/font-awesome-animation.css' );
}
```

Comment: All is well. Answered by @DaveLak with the following for clarity

Building a Genesis child theme which contains /css/font-awesome-animation.css so get_stylesheet_directory_uri() was still required.